# unable to return my sql connection object from web service to asp.net project

Tags: asp.net

This my web service code :

```
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Web;
    using System.Web.Services;
    using System.Data.Sql;
    using System.Data.SqlClient;
    
    namespace DBwebService
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Summary description for WebService1
        /// </summary>
        [WebService(Namespace = "http://kse.org/")]
        [WebServiceBinding(ConformsTo = WsiProfiles.BasicProfile1_1)]
        [System.ComponentModel.ToolboxItem(false)]
        // To allow this Web Service to be called from script, using ASP.NET AJAX, uncomment the following line. 
        // [System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptService]
        public class WebService1 : System.Web.Services.WebService
        {
    
            string ConnectionString = "Data Source=Shumaila-PC;Initial Catalog=kse;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=sa;Password=sa";
            public SqlConnection Conn;
    
            [WebMethod]
            
            public void SqlConn()
            {   
    
                    Conn = new SqlConnection(ConnectionString);
                   // Conn.Open();

                }
                //catch (SqlException ex)
               //{
                    
                //    //Console.WriteLine( "Connection Unsuccessful " + ex.Message);
               
                //}
          
        }
    }
```

I need to return my sql connection object so that i can call it in my asp.net pid roject. but when i did

```
public SqlConnection SqlConn()
```

and

```
return.Conn();
```

this gives me the following error

> Server Error in '/' Application. Parser Error Description: An error occurred during the parsing of a resource required to service this request. Please review the following specific parse error details and modify your source file appropriately.
>
> Parser Error Message: Could not create type 'DBwebService.WebService1'.
>
> Source Error:
>
> Line 1: <%@ WebService Language="C#" CodeBehind="WebService1.asmx.cs" Class="DBwebService.WebService1" %>
>
> Source File: /WebService1.asmx Line: 1
>
> Version Information: Microsoft .NET Framework Version:4.0.30319; ASP.NET Version:4.0.30319.1 --. Metadata contains a reference that cannot be resolved: 'http://localhost:50387/WebService1.asmx'. The content type text/html; charset=utf-8 of the response message does not match the content type of the binding (application/soap+xml; charset=utf-8). If using a custom encoder, be sure that the IsContentTypeSupported method is implemented properly. The first 1024 bytes of the response were: ' Server Error in '/' Application. Parser Error '. The remote server returned an error: (500) Internal Server Error. If the service is defined in the current solution, try building the solution and adding the service reference again.

Comment: it was typo. i have coded Conn

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your web service should expose a method which accepts the signup data as an argument to the method. The service can then commit that data to the database and then return an Ack/Nack response to the UI.

Answer (score 2):

My God are you serious? You should not even think to return a connection from a service. you should return the data you load with a query which is executed using that connection. that is, move all the logic of what you want to do with the connection in the calling code inside a DAL class library and return the results only.

Comment: I am new to .net 

But i want to send my signup page data to database . Signup page is an another asp.net project. Please suggest me how can I achieve it

Comment: This is not .net but basic design sense. A web service is a wholly inappropriate application boundary to pass these types of objects across. It makes my hair stand on end just considering it.

Answer (score 0):

HMM come to think of it connection object is not serialized you have to declare your object as serialize-able only to do the above task, only primitive types are auto serialize-able.

Comment: While serialization may be the solution to have it cross boundaries, there is no reason to pass a database connection instance across boundaries even with serialization.